# How to use jalali calendar in angular material 2?

Tags: angular-material2, jalali-calendar

I use mat-datepicker in my app but when I change the LOCAL_ID to 'fa-IR' the arrangement of months and the days of month is incorrect as seen in this picture: 
 [image: material datepicker].

how can I do it correctly?

[sample link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kvdteq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [reported](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10972) this bug to angular material and they introduced a repository which solve this problem (as workaround).

Should rewrite DateAdapter with this [one](https://github.com/peymanebrahimi/AngularMaterialJalaliDate).

```
 {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: JalaliMomentDateAdapter, deps: 
 [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
 {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: JALALI_MOMENT_FORMATS},
```

Thanks from [peyman ebrahimi](https://github.com/peymanebrahimi) for all of his efforts.